# Does it make sense to use Thread/Process-data as seed to generate random numbers?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, random, random-seed

Some additional questions:
Is there some technical way to use thread-data (stored in RAM, i.ex. several sectors), use it as seed for lets say a couple rounds in a mersenne-twister ?

What about JavaScript?

Are there any Pros and Cons for that ? (let's say it reveals unwillingly data about the scheduler)

Are there already any 'cryptographically safe' random number generator - and what's their (algorithm) technique/usual approach on this ?

**I know the guidelines.

Comment: JavaScript is not multi-threaded

Comment: @Pointy thanks to worker threads and shared arrays, it is. Not that this makes any sense though, there are no pros, and the cons are "if you're asking this question, you're not going to be able to identify the problems your (P)RNG code will have". Use a normal, well-tested (P)RNG library instead.

Comment: Thread-data: different program-states can form a number as seed

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well yes, in a sense I guess; more like the browser is multi-threaded (imo)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you have any recommendations for good PRNG libaries - or is does it even make sense to differentiate between them ? are there some cryptographically approved ones? And do you know some, that implement thread-based seeds/ or I guess random number generation

Comment: JS can spawn workers within its own framework, whether it's in a browser or not (i.e. V8 backing Node.js). This wasn't the case for the longest time, so it's tempting to still think it's single threaded, but it's been able to run multithreaded ever since workers got adopted by all JS engine vendors back in 2010. Each script gets one thread, but any script can also spawn any number of separately threaded workers it needs.

Comment: @rnnUSer11 remember that asking for tools or libraries is literally one of the "how to get your question closed](/help/on-topic). Just search the web/npm etc for a highly rater (P)RNG library. (And remember that you're not looking for "actively maintained": we figured out random numbers decades ago, an 8 year old JS library will still generate the same random numbers as 8 years ago).

Comment: Not really, since you're asking about JS, which would have a completely different set of answers if those kinds of questions didn't get closed pretty soon after folks find it (unless the poster shows you've literally done all their research already and despite that, weren't able to get the answer they needed. Any off-topic question can be made on-topic if you can demonstrate you're using SO as your last resort after exhaustive research)